# How to prove $N=13\times12v+6\times19u$ is a solution for the system?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Well, I have a system of congruences it is :
$$n\equiv13\pmod{19}$$
$$n\equiv6\pmod{12}$$
I'm trying to prove that for any pair of integers $(u,v)$ the number $N=13\times12v+6\times19u$ is a solution to the system of equations above.

actually i don't know even how to begin :(.

Oh i forgot : $(u,v)$ satisfy $19u+12v=1$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Answer (score 1):

i got it it's very easy actually :
well, we have $19u+12v=1$ and that implies $19u=-12v+1$.
$$19u\equiv1\pmod{-12}\implies 19u\equiv1\pmod{12}\implies19u\times6\equiv6\pmod{12}$$
$$12\times13v\equiv0\pmod{12}$$
adding both of the two congruences give us :
$$19u\times6+12\times13v=N\equiv6\pmod{12}$$.
and the same way to prove that $N\equiv13\pmod{19}$.